# Joining Three MySQL Tables and Get The Maximum Value From One Table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables which I want to join.

First one is "User" table.

```
+---------+--------------+---------+
|Id       |UserName      |blah     |
+---------+--------------+---------+
|1        |Amila         |blah     |
+---------+--------------+---------+
|2        |Kamal         |blah     |
+---------+--------------+---------+
|3        |Nuwan         |blah     |
+---------+--------------+---------+
```

Second one is "Images" table. It contains all the images that uploaded by users. Also if Type==PI and maximum id would be user's current profile image.

```
+---------+--------------+---------+---------+
|Id       |Image         |Type     |User     |
+---------+--------------+---------+---------+
|1        |12358.jpg     |PI       |1        |
+---------+--------------+---------+---------+
|2        |12589.jpg     |PI       |2        |
+---------+--------------+---------+---------+
|3        |45862.jpg     |Other    |2        |
+---------+--------------+---------+---------+
|4        |35698.jpg     |PI       |1        |
+---------+--------------+---------+---------+
```

Third one "Comments" table holds all the comments.

```
+---------+--------------+---------+
|Id       |Comment       |User     |
+---------+--------------+---------+
|1        |blah blah...  |1        |
+---------+--------------+---------+
|2        |blah blah...  |1        |
+---------+--------------+---------+
|3        |blah blah...  |2        |
+---------+--------------+---------+
```

What I wanted to do is write a query that returns

Users.Id, Users.UserName, Images.Image (which max Id & Type==PI), Comments.Id, Comments.Comment

Basically it's all about joining three tables.

This is my code for that

```
SELECT U.`Id`, U.`UserName`, I.`Image`, C.`Id`, C.`Comment` 
FROM `Users` U 
INNER JOIN `Images` I ON I.`Image` = (
    SELECT MAX(I.`Image`) FROM `Images` WHERE I.`User` = U.`Id`
) AND I.`Type` = 'PI' 
INNER JOIN `Comments` C ON C.`User` = U.`Id`
```

But this returns all the images in Images table. As example it returns both images of User 1. I need only last uploaded image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the result descending to get the last of them on top and then limit the result to 1. Something like that will do it:

```
SELECT U.`Id`, U.`UserName`, I.`Image`, C.`Id`, C.`Comment`
FROM `Users` U
INNER JOIN `Images` I ON I.`User`=U.`Id`
INNER JOIN Comments c ON C.`User` = U.`Id`
WHERE I.`Id` IN ( SELECT MAX(`Id`) FROM `Images` GROUP BY `User` )
ORDER BY I.`Image` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the result that you need. The purpose of having a `LEFT JOIN` on the subquery is to have a record for every username even if it has no matched record on table `Images`. The subquery on the `LEFT JOIN` has also a subquery which gets the latest upladed `image` for every `user`.

```
SELECT  a.Id, 
        a.UserName, 
        c.Image, 
        b.Id, 
        b.Comment
FROM    User a
        INNER JOIN Comments b
            ON a.ID = b.User
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  i.*
            FROM    Images i
                    INNER JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT  User, MAX(ID) ID
                        FROM    Images
                        WHERE   Type = 'PI'
                        GROUP   BY User
                    ) o ON  i.User = o.User
                            AND i.ID = o.ID
        ) c ON  a.ID = c.User
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cffb8/1)

Otherwise, if you are sure that you have atleast one matching record on table `Images`, you can use `INNER JOIN` on all joins,

```
SELECT  a.Id, 
        a.UserName, 
        c.Image, 
        b.Id, 
        b.Comment
FROM    User a
        INNER JOIN Comments b
            ON a.ID = b.User
        INNER JOIN  Images c
            ON a.ID = c.User
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  User, MAX(ID) ID
            FROM    Images
            WHERE   Type = 'PI'
            GROUP   BY User
        ) o ON  i.User = o.User
                AND i.ID = o.ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cffb8/3)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the query that you are aiming for:

```
SELECT U.`Id`, U.`UserName`, I.`Image`, C.`Id`, C.`Comment` 
FROM `Users` U INNER JOIN
     `Images` I
     ON I.id = (SELECT MAX(I.id)
                FROM `Images`
                WHERE `User` = U.`Id` and `Type` = 'PI'
               ) INNER JOIN 
     `Comments` C
     ON C.`User` = U.`Id` ;
```

I do find this a strange way to write the query.  My inclination is to do the `max()` comparison on a separate step:

```
SELECT U.`Id`, U.`UserName`, I.`Image`, C.`Id`, C.`Comment` 
FROM `Users` U INNER JOIN
     `Images` I
     ON i.`User` = U.`Id` INNER JOIN
     (select user, max(I.id) as maxid
      FROM `Images`
      WHERE `Type` = 'PI'
     ) maxi
     ON i.id = maxi.maxid join
     `Comments` C
     ON C.`User` = U.`Id` ;
```